# Battery dimensioning

Tags: batteries

For a school project I'd like to put a "fit pc 2" (a  RaspberryPi-like) on a flying device.
As the fit PC2 is supposed to be directly plugged  to energy, I'd like to buy a battery to let it work in the air.

I have the folowing information written on the fit pc 2 box :

```
Input: DC12V (9V to 15V tolerant)
Adaptater: AC100-240V -> 12V 1.5A
```

I found the flowing  battery :
http://www.selectronic.fr/media/pdf/6345-7-fiche-technique.pdf

It says "NX - 12V - 2.9Ah - 98.5x79x55.5mm". As far as I understand this would work and let me use the computer for a theoretically 2hours.

Is this right ? Should I only care about making it 12V and n*1.5 Ah (n being how much hours I want the battery to last) or is there any other characteristics I should take into consideration ?

Needless to say I'm far from being good in Electrical Engineering... ;)

Comment: The weight of the battery. How much can your flying device carry? That battery weights 1.10kg (2.43lbs).

Comment: We're using a paramotor drone, the lift is ensured by a sail, not directly by motors like in quadcopters so it won't be a problem. I guess your comment means you think the battery is ok from an electrical point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The other option you have are 3-cell LiPo batteries. These tend to have a fully charged voltage of ~12.6V, with a typical voltage of ~11.1V. When fully discharged they will drop down to about 9V. All of that is within the spec of your computers input - you say it is tolerant of 9-15V.

LiPo's will be far lighter for a given energy density which is why they are frequently used in RC Helicopters and planes. For example a 6Ah LiPo weighs about 400g, vs the 1.2kg of the 2.9Ah battery in your link - twice the capacity, 1/3 of the weight!

The thing with LiPos you have to be careful of is to include protection circuits for over discharge - many have this built in - and over charge. Charging is usually done with a special balance charger to ensure all cells get an equal charge.

Answer (score 0):

12V batteries are likely to be heavy, as Dan pointed out. It looks like a laptop battery in size and voltage, and for a flying device you'll want something more similar to a cellphone battery.

So the first thing I'd do is to reduce the required voltage to something in the order of 3V. It will mean that you'll be served by a single-cell LiPo battery. But 5 V can also be fine, and it will open some more options.

Then I would address the more general power requirement. The original Raspberry Pi consumes 2.5/3 W, which is in the sub-Ampère range.

I suppose you won't be flying your "drone" for more than an hour (most likely less), so a 1000+ mAh battery should be more than enough.

Note that you could in principle use a very low power controller and use the same battery for the

Comment: It's not a Pi, it's an Atom-based device, and it seems to have a required 12V input. Presumably the poster has reasons for using this particular device.